# Транзакции в Spring MVC. Ищу оптимальное решение

Tags: spring, mvc, transaction

У меня есть Spring MVC приложение в котором пока только одна Entity и это User. Я так же настроил Spring Security и подключил MySQL. Теперь всё работает корректно, но я столкнулся вот с какой проблемой:
Мой класс UserDAO реализован с помощью SessionFactory. Изначально я разместил аннотации     @Transactional на уровне Service, но у меня не работает метод updateUser() класса UserServise потому что я в нём дважды обращаюсь к базе данных, сначала что бы получить юзера из БД, получить от него значения служебных полей, присвоить их юзеру который передан в метод. А второй раз что бы сохранить изменённого юзера.

```
@Transactional
public void update(User user) {
    User fromDb = userDAO.findById(user.getId());

    LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    user.setCreated(fromDb.getCreated());
    user.setUpdated(currentDateTime);

    user.setRole(fromDb.getRole());
    user.setActive(fromDb.isActive());

    userDAO.saveOrUpdate(user);
}
```

В итоге при обращении к этому методу я получаю вот такой стектрейс:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.igormeshalkin.entity.User#18]
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:696)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:287)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:230)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:95)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:616)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:609)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:604)
    com.igormeshalkin.dao.UserDAO.saveOrUpdate(UserDAO.java:47)
    com.igormeshalkin.dao.UserDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a1ea7647.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
    com.igormeshalkin.dao.UserDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$96ca5c0c.saveOrUpdate(<generated>)
    com.igormeshalkin.service.UserService.update(UserService.java:61)
    com.igormeshalkin.service.UserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$939a238d.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    com.igormeshalkin.service.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e914df9e.update(<generated>)
    com.igormeshalkin.controller.UserController.saveUpdatedUser(UserController.java:67)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
```

Я переношу @Transactional ну уровень DAO и всё работает корректно.
Теперь я опасаюсь что позднее когда у меня появятся другие сущности и мне будет нужно в одном Service обращаться к разным DAO эти обращения будут происходить в разных транзакциях и я получу новые проблемы.

Могу ли я оставить @Transactional на уровне DAO, а в будущем при необходимости управлять транзакциями на уровне Service вручную в тех методах где эта необходимость возникла?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в реализации сервиса.

Вы прочитали объект из БД и загрузили его в память. А потом пытаетесь сохранить второй объект с таким же идентификатором. То есть корень проблемы в том, что пытаетесь сохранять `user` тот, что пришел в метод `update`, а нужно сделать изменения в объекте загруженном из БД и его же и сохранить:

```
@Transactional
public void update(User user) {
    User fromDb = userDAO.findById(user.getId());

    LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    fromDb.setUpdated(currentDateTime);
    
    // тут нужно заполнить все другие поля в fromDb используя поля из user
    ...
 
    userDAO.saveOrUpdate(fromDb);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Мне это помогло.